# SQL Server 2014 Express has reached database size limit. What is the quickest solution?

Tags: database, sql-server

My SQL Server 2014 Express database has reached database size limit.

What is the quickest solution to get back up and running? Is Express software the same as the full version, with just some limitations, or is it a complete different software?

i.e. Can I just go to Microsoft store online, order a key for full version, and type it in to the current Express to activate full features, or do I need to do full uninstall of Express, reinstall of full version, copy database and such?

Comment: The comparison between the Express versions and the other versions of MSSQL Server 2014 are well documented.  If you have reach the database limit for the Express edition, then your only choice is to reduce the size of the database, or upgrade to the paid version of MSSQL Server 2014.

Comment: I know that. That is not the question.

Comment: They are separate products.  You would to uninstall MSSQL Server 2014 Express and install a different edition of MSSQL Server 2014.  I made the comment I made, because literally submitting that single sentence as an answer, does not make sense to me,

Comment: Actually we were able to upgrade it using Express Installation Center. No uninstall needed but thanks

Comment: When I have done this task myself, I uninstall the edition I no longer want, then install the edition I do want.  Since the database isn't touched in the process it seems harmless enough.